# Menu bar in ubuntu laptop isn't showing available wifi

Tags: wireless

I've been trying to connect my ubuntu​(dual-booted with windows 10) laptop to wifi,but the menu bar isn't showing the "enable wifi" option and available wifi networks.I have checked previous questions, suggested commands,YouTube videos,etc. but none of them helped.I'm getting different(from what expected) results for the suggested commands.Please give a solution for this?

Comment: Could please post what commands you have tried so far?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the network manager using:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```